# Display same content on 2 I2C LCD modules

Tags: pi-pico, lcd

I am trying to build a motorized head of puppet/animatronics and for the eyes, I am using 2 LCD LED Module SSD1306 (1 per eye).
I am using a Raspberry Pi pico. I got the code working to display animated eyes on the LCD, but I am using 1 pair of SDA/SCL per eye and therefore there is a slight delay between the 2 eyes.

It gives a funny look (imagine eyes blinking not in sync :) ), but it is not the intended effect.

I am thinking to use a single pair of SDA/SCL instead of two, and just jump both LCD modules together. I don't have a spare, so I didn't dare to connect. As they are the same models, the addresses are the same. **Is there any risk to that?**

If it is not recommended, then I'll try to tune my code (I am using `uasyncio`)

Comment: Without code and schematic this is meaningless.

Comment: @Milliways I am not asking for code fixing or circuit information. If you don't know the answer you don't have to be mean.

Comment: If your question is can you safely connect 2 I²C devices with the same address to the same interface the answer is yes BUT it is unlikely to work if you are attempting to READ data - so without details the question remains unanswerable. I don't understand why people are so reluctant to post details of their problems.

Comment: Off-topic - the Pi/Pico is irrelevant to any answer.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @Milliways ok fair enough. I'll update the question with my current code and pinout.

Comment: @joan it wasn't clear to me before as I tried to solve my current solution rather than looking at the right solution. And pi/pico being my H/W could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The PiPico has a dual core processor.
It is possible (indeed simple) to run 2 processes (or 2 copies of a process) simultaneously on both cores.

In the absence of detail of the code (or language) you are using it is not possible to suggest a more detailed solution.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look (after I update my question with some code)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why it (connecting two of these displays to the same I2C bus) wouldn't work and I don't think that there is much chance of causing damage.

Since I2C is open collector, there is no reason for any outputs to 'fight'; each line is either pulled high by the resistors or driven to ground. From an electrical point of view, it's no different to there being two (or more) different devices on the I2C bus, which is exactly what it's designed for. So I can't see the IO pins on the Pico or displays being damaged by being connected together.

I think these modules have built-in pull-up resistors, so you may end up with a non-standard pull-up on your bus, but over short distances (low cable capacitance), this should not be a problem either.

I think that the only avenue for damage would be if the data being sent ended up putting the display in an improper state and I can't recall ever seeing one of these displays being permanently damaged by a software setting.

If I had two of these displays, I would be game to try this right now to confirm.